# Are AutoCAD usage questions on topic here?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Are AutoCAD usage questions on topic here? [The CAD proposal didn't pick up steam and was closed](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/80927/computer-aided-design-cad).

Comment: Yep. Check out [tag:autocad] and [tag:computer-aided-design].