# Are CAD software usage related questions on topic here?

Tags: discussion

Say, I want to know how to convert 3D Polylines into 2D polylines in [*draftsight*](https://www.3ds.com/products-services/draftsight-cad-software/), or the questions that are covered in [area 51 proposal here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93545/computer-aided-design-cad).

My questions have to do with how to use CAD system to achieve something that I want, which is geared more towards drafting, rather than engineering ( calculation) side.

I've read the response to [this question](https://engineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/412/3353), and [this question](https://engineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/103/3353), and I am still unable to tell what is the official stance of this site.

Mind to enlighten?

Comment: That question was *Are AutoCAD usage questions on topic here?* and my response was *Yep.* I think perhaps you are overthinking things a bit.

Comment: Yes, we haven't had a lot of pure CAD questions, but they are welcome.

Comment: @hazzey, are you sure they are welcome? [The link in the question  Are Questions About Engineering Software On-Topic? What questions?](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/230/are-there-any-viable-open-source-modeling-software-packages) already being removed. So I am very unsure whether CAD questions are welcomed or not

Comment: See the questions tagged [tag:autocad] examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR - Yes, CAD questions are on-topic for the site.

---

Your question [has been pretty well addressed before](https://engineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103/are-questions-about-engineering-software-on-topic-what-questions), and [Trevor's answer](https://engineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/105/16) along with [my answer](https://engineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/104/16) provide more detail as to the community's expectations regarding CAD based questions.  They are certainly on-topic for the site.

Within one of [your comments](https://engineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/430/are-cad-software-usage-related-questions-on-topic-here#comment904_430), you expressed concern that the answers weren't valid as one of the subject questions in that meta post has since been deleted.

For the sake of your question and others who don't have privileges to see deleted posts, here's a screenshot of what was asked:
[image: Screenshot of list question]

List and off-site resource request questions like that one aren't a good fit for the StackExchange Q&A format and [our policy is to close them as off-topic](https://engineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10/368).  The general concerns are that the information grows stale and questions like that are honeypots for spamvertisements that don't provide value to the site.

So don't worry about the particular example that happens to have been deleted.  Read and follow the guidance presented in Trevor's and my answers.